# C# and Arduino displaying time in WinForm using Stopwatch class

Tags: c#, multithreading, arduino, serial-port

I am new to Arduino and programming with threads.
I programmed 5 buttons in Arduino - when you press the button something happens. 
I would like to receive that data in C# (C# reads the data from port sent from Adruino. 
This enables us to know which stopwatch to start). 
When the button is pressed, a stopwatch starts and displays elapsed time countinuously. 
The problem is that I can't get it to work with multiple buttons, example: I have 5 buttons which can be pressed any time, 
but the current code can handle only 1 button. 
I would really appreciate your help, because I have been struggling for days.

Arduino code:

```
const int button1 = 3;
const int button2 = 5;

int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;

int buttonState1 = 0;
int buttonState2 = 0;


void setup() 
{
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  buttonState1 = digitalRead(button1);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(button2);

  // *** BUTTON 1 ***
  if (buttonState1 == LOW && counter1==0)
  {
    //Serial.println("connected");
    counter1++;
    delay(100);
  }
  else if (buttonState1 == HIGH && counter1==1) 
  {
    //Serial.println("ready");
    counter1++;
    delay(100);
  }
  else if(buttonState1 == LOW && counter1==2)
  {
    Serial.println("start");
    counter1++;
    delay(100);
  }
  else if(buttonState1 == HIGH && counter1==3)
  {
    Serial.println("stop");
    counter1++;
    delay(100);
  }


  // *** BUTTON 2 ***
  if (buttonState2 == LOW && counter2 == 0)
  {
    //Serial.println("connected");
    counter2++;
    delay(100);
  }
  else if (buttonState2 == HIGH && counter2 == 1) 
  {
    //Serial.println("ready");
    counter2++;
    delay(100);
  }
  else if(buttonState2 == LOW && counter2 == 2)
  {
    Serial.println("start2");
    counter2++;
    delay(100);
  }
  else if(buttonState2 == HIGH && counter2 == 3)
  {
    Serial.println("stop2");
    counter2++;
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

C# code:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();

// display time from first stopwatch
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblSec.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + 
   stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString() + "." + 
   stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString();
}

// display time from second stopwatch
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   label1.Text = stopwatch2.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + 
   stopwatch2.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString() + "." + 
   stopwatch2.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString();
}
```

**Edit: It works.**
I open the port and start a new thread when button is pressed. Loop checks for values which come from port and start/stop a stopwatch.

```
public void PortReadLine()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        string portValue = myPort.ReadLine();
        switch (portValue)
        {
            case "start\r":
                stopwatch.Start();
                break;

            case "start2\r":
                stopwatch2.Start();
                break;

            case "stop\r":
                stopwatch.Stop();
                break;

            case "stop2\r":
                stopwatch2.Stop();
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void button1_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    myPort.PortName = "COM3";
    myPort.Open();

    Thread threadPort = new Thread(PortReadLine);
    threadPort.Start();
}
```

Comment: So which  one works?  Also might be instructive to see the relevant parts of your Arduino code.  And if this is the issue, I'll be happy to put it in an answer, but have you enabled both Timer1 and Timer2 and set the Interval property of each?

Comment: If you press button1 first and then button2, only button1 is executed, because it was pressed first. If you press button2 first, then button1 doesn't work. I pasted Arduino code. Yes timers are enabled and work.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you press a button and `ThreadMethodStop()` is called, it looks as though you're disabling the serial port:

```
if (data == "stop\r")
{
    stopwatch.Stop();
    myPort.Close();  // <== here
}
if (data == "stop2\r")
{
    stopwatch2.Stop();
    myPort.Close();  // <== and here
}
```

Try not closing the port on the commented lines.

Next, your `counter` variables seem to be keeping track of state, but go out of range after the button is released, and nothing in `loop()` ever return them to values that will satisfy your `&&` condition:

```
else if(buttonState2 == LOW && counter2 == 2)
{
   Serial.println("start2");
   counter2++;
   delay(100);
}
else if(buttonState2 == HIGH && counter2 == 3)
{
   Serial.println("stop2");
   counter2++;
   delay(100);
}
```

See how after you increment `counter2` for example, its value will be 4 and will therefore never again satisfy the condition in your `if` statements?  I think therefore you need

```
else if(buttonState2 == HIGH && counter2 == 3)
{
  Serial.println("stop2");
  counter2 = 2; // make ready to return to start2 condition OR
  counter2 = 0; // return to initial state, do one of these...
  delay(100);
}
```

And of course do the same for the other button.

Comment: I also tried not closing port at all, but still doesn't work

Comment: Please take a look at my edited answer and [take a peek at this, thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: That is an option (my idea is to reset counters via C# code), but the problem is in C# code. I don't know how to continuously read data from Arduino and in the same time run stopwatch and display elapsed time in real-time. Now it works only on first iteration (button2 which is pressed after button1 doesn't work or vice versa).